# sum input fields value if they have the same value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I'm getting stuck on the logic to use to accomplish this in javascript/jquery and could use some help if anyone had any ideas.

I have table which shows the per item cost of the products on an invoice.

The goal is to find all the products by their class(currently shirtcountrow and hoodiecountrow but there will be more later) and combine the ones that have the same value.

The table currently looks like this:

```
<table id="productmathtable">
<tr>    
<td>Shirt</td>       
<td><input class="shirtcountrow" type="text" value="4" style="width:60px"> x <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="25" style="width:60px"> = </td>      
<td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="100" style="width:60px"></td>
</tr>
<tr>         
<td>Shirt</td>       
<td><input class="shirtcountrow" type="text" value="2" style="width:60px"> x <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="25" style="width:60px"> = </td>       
<td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="50" style="width:60px"></td>       
</tr>
<tr>         
<td>Shirt</td>       
<td><input class="shirtcountrow" type="text" value="2" style="width:60px"> x     <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="25" style="width:60px"> = </td>      
 <td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="50" style="width:60px"></td>     
 </tr><tr>       
<td>Hoodie</td>     
 <td><input class="hoodiecountrow" type="text" value="4" style="width:60px"> x <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="35" style="width:60px"> = </td>         
<td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="140" style="width:60px"></td>      
</tr>
<tr>         
 <td>Hoodie</td>        
 <td><input class="hoodiecountrow" type="text" value="4" style="width:60px"> x <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="35" style="width:60px"> = </td>         
<td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="140" style="width:60px"></td></tr>     
</table>
```

And I want it to look like this after a jquery/javascript function is preformed:

```
<table id="productmathtable">
<tr>    
<td>Shirt</td>       
<td><input class="shirtcountrow" type="text" value="8" style="width:60px"> x <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="25" style="width:60px"> = </td>      
<td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="200" style="width:60px"></td>
</tr> 
<td>Hoodie</td>     
 <td><input class="hoodiecountrow" type="text" value="8" style="width:60px"> x <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="35" style="width:60px"> = </td>         
<td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="280" style="width:60px"></td>      
</tr>   
</table>
```

I am pretty sure i need to change my html so it's easier to identify each part that i want to change, but im not exactly sure how

Answer (score 1):

Granted your html is not optimized, but rather than rethink all that, here is a method to tally them up and then rewrite the table with the aggregate totals. The one thing I did change was in the class of the quantity field - I standardized them to all have the class 'quantity' instead.

```js
let uniques = []
$('#productmathtable tr').each(function() {
  // do we have this one yet?
  let thisname = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text().trim()
  let exists = uniques.findIndex(u => u.name.toLowerCase() === thisname.toLowerCase())
  let q = +$(this).find('.quantity').val();
  let p = +$(this).find('.productpricerow').val();
  if (exists > -1) {
    uniques[exists].quantity += q;
  } else {
    uniques.push({
      name: thisname,
      quantity: q,
      price: p
    });
  }
  $(this).remove();
})

uniques.forEach(o => {
  let row = `<tr>
    <td>${o.name}</td>
    <td><input class="quantity" type="text" value="${o.quantity}" style="width:60px"> x <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="${o.price}" style="width:60px"> = </td>
    <td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="${o.quantity * o.price}" style="width:60px"></td>
  </tr>`;
  $('#productmathtable').append(row)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="productmathtable">
  <tr>
    <td>Shirt</td>
    <td><input class="quantity" type="text" value="4" style="width:60px"> x <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="25" style="width:60px"> = </td>
    <td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="100" style="width:60px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shirt</td>
    <td><input class="quantity" type="text" value="2" style="width:60px"> x <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="25" style="width:60px"> = </td>
    <td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="50" style="width:60px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shirt</td>
    <td><input class="quantity" type="text" value="2" style="width:60px"> x <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="25" style="width:60px"> = </td>
    <td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="50" style="width:60px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hoodie</td>
    <td><input class="quantity" type="text" value="4" style="width:60px"> x <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="35" style="width:60px"> = </td>
    <td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="140" style="width:60px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hoodie</td>
    <td><input class="quantity" type="text" value="4" style="width:60px"> x <input class="productpricerow" type="text" value="35" style="width:60px"> = </td>
    <td class="tabletotalrow"><input class="productotalrow totalrow" type="text" value="140" style="width:60px"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually I noticed it works in this case because there is only two matching .productpricerow but if there is a third it only includes two, any tips?

Comment: You will have to rename the class for the quantity field Dash see how I did it in my example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xmk1rzqs/ See this fiddle, I added another hoodie with the class quantity but set the value of this one to 45 so that it would be different, but the script still only prints out two when there should be three

Answer (score 0):

To re-formulate the question a bit more concretely... It appears that you are saying, for each classname in some list of classnames, you want to do the following transformation:

Find all the tr's in #productmathtable that contain an input with the given classname; set the first such input's "value" attribute to the sum of the matching "classname" inputs' "value" attributes; similarly sum the producttotalrows' "value" attributes; and then remove the other matching tr's.

Of course, it's easier to do this sort of manipulation on the raw data *before* creating the dom, if possible.  But something like the following (untested) code should do the trick...

```
// Get an array of all the tr's.
var trlist = $("#productmathtable > tr").toArray();

// Apply tranformation function for each classname.
["shirtcountrow", "hoodiecountrow"].forEach(
    function(cname) {
        var ctotal = 0;
        var ptotal = 0;
        var combined = null;

        // Use Array.filter to get the set of matching tr's for this classname.
        var subset = trlist.filter(function (tr) {
            return ($("input."+cname, tr).length > 0);
        });

        // Walk through this list, updating the dom as you go.
        subset.forEach(function (tr) {
            // Update cached values.
            ctotal += parseInt($("input."+cname, tr).attr("value"));
            ptotal += parseInt($("input.producttotalrows", tr).attr("value"));

            if (combined === null) {
                // First item: just keep it, as-is.
                combined = tr;
            } else {
                // Subsequent items...
                // Update values in dom.
                $("input."+cname, combined).attr("value", ctotal);
                $("input.producttotalrows", combined).attr("value", ptotal);

                // Remove now-extraneous tr from dom.
                $(tr).remove();
            }
        });
    }
);
```